# How to get the last message of a specific discord channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I've been trying to get the last message of a channel writing a command in another channel.

I want to do something like this:

Channel 1 : (I write) "Get last message of channel 2
channel 2: Last message is ("Hello");
Channel 1: i receive the last message of channel 2 saying, the last message of channel 2 is . "Hello".

My code is this, but isn't working.

```
 if (message.channel.id === '613573853565681671') {
   message.channel.fetchMessages().then(collected => {
     const filtered = collected.filter(message => message.author.bot);
     const lastMessages = filtered.first(1); //Get the last message of this channel.
     const TextMessages = `${lastMessages[0].content}`;
     console.log(TextMessages + " is the last message of aviso jobs")

     if (TextMessages === "look") { //If the last message of this channel is look then go to the other channel

       if (message.channel.id === '613553889433747477') {
         message.channel.fetchMessages().then(collected => {
           const filtered = collected.filter(message => message.author.bot);
           const lastMessages2 = filtered.first(1); //Get the last message of this other channel.
           const TextMessages2 = `${lastMessages2[0].content}`;
           console.log(TextMessages2 + " is the last message of bot")
         });
       }
     }
   });
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm having troubles understanding your code so here's how i would do it, maybe it'll help you:

```
  if (message.content.startsWith("!lastmessage")) {
    let args = message.content.split(" "); //find every word of the message
    if (args.length > 1) { //make sure that there is at least 1 argument, which should be the target channel's id
      let target = message.guild.channels.find(c => c.id == args[1]) || null; // find the targeted channel
      if (target) { // make sure that the targeted channel exists, if it exists then fetch its last message
        target
          .fetchMessages({ limit: 1 })
          .then(f =>
            message.channel.send(
              `Last message from <#${target.id}> is...\n> ${f.first().content}`
            ) // send the last message to the initial channel
          );
      } else { //if target doesn't exist, send an error
        message.channel.send("Target does not exist!");
      }
    }
  }
```